# Calculate IP device total up and down time from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate total UP and Down time of IP device from SQL table. I am inserting a row in a table after every connection up and down event of a particular IP device.

My sample table is :

```
create table connected (IP nvarchar (50), stat char(10), ts datetime);

insert into connected values
('10.0.0.1','down',cast('2022-09-13 4:00:00.000' as datetime)),
('10.0.0.2','down',cast('2022-09-13 6:30:00.000' as datetime)),
('10.0.0.1','up',cast('2022-09-13 4:30:00.000' as datetime)),
('10.0.0.2','up',cast('2022-09-13 6:55:00.000' as datetime)),
('10.0.0.3','down',cast('2022-09-13 18:00:00.000' as datetime)),
('10.0.0.1','down',cast('2022-09-13 6:00:00.000' as datetime)),
('10.0.0.1','up',cast('2022-09-13 6:20:00.000' as datetime));
```

There can be multiple events of a IP device in a single day but it is sure that if any particular ip device have entry of down then the next entry for that particular device be up.
Now I want two results

1. Device IP- and total up and down time between two dates.
   For example :

```
Ip---------  Totalup time-------- Total Down Time
10.0.0.1----  1400min -------------- 50min
10.0.0.2------ 1415min---------------25min   
10.0.0.3------1080min --------------60min ( this should be calculate based on current time)
```

2. Detailed entry for each device with total down time

```
IP-----------------Down Time ------------------ Up Time -------  Total DownTime    
10.0.0.1-------13-09-2022 4:00:000 ----- 13-09-2022 4:30:000 ---------30min    
10.0.0.1-------13-09-2022 6:00:000 ----- 13-09-2022 6:20:000 ---------20min       
10.0.0.2-------13-09-2022 6:30:000 ----- 13-09-2022 6:55:000 ---------25min    
10.0.0.3-------13-09-2022 18:00:000 ----- 13-09-2022 19:00:000 --------60min (based on current time because for 10.0.0.3 we dont have up event in the table)
```

Comment: The datetimes in the input sample is different than the datetimes in the output results, this is confusing!

Comment: Hi Ahmed, Thanks for replying. Actually , the output is with some sample date , please considered the actual date & time given in insert queries.

Comment: I don't understand the logic for `10.0.0.3------1080min --------------60min` where does 1080 come from?

Comment: @Charlieface , For 10.0.0.3 , It shows the result for particular 13th sep 2022 date . the device was down at 18:00 , so the uptime was 60min *18hrs = 1080 min is up time and when I am executing this query , it will calculate the downtime with that time.

Comment: So you are calculating each day separately, and assuming the device was up at `00:00:00`?

Comment: suppose , If I have to check on particular date i.e 13th september, what was the status of all IP devices then it should show the result based on 24hrs. If there is no down entry for particular IP device on that day , then it will be considered as 24hrs UP. And In case I select two dates , then accordingly it will show result like 1st sep to 30th sep.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LEAD` to calculate the next timestamp for each row, then simply aggregate the results.

```sql
SELECT
  c.IP,
  UpTime =   SUM(CASE WHEN c.stat = 'up'   THEN DATEDIFF(second, c.ts, c.NextTime) END) / 60,
  DownTime = SUM(CASE WHEN c.stat = 'down' THEN DATEDIFF(second, c.ts, c.NextTime) END) / 60
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      NextTime = LEAD(c.ts, 1, GETDATE()) OVER (PARTITION BY c.IP ORDER BY c.ts)
    FROM connected c
) c
GROUP BY
  c.IP;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/khMZRvHd)

Since the default given for `LEAD` is `GETDATE()` it will depend on your timezone.